# Applet is invisible in JavaFX application

Tags: java, swing, javafx, applet

I am in the process of converting my GUI from Swing to JavaFX (so I can add custom styling things more easily).

I had my application working in Swing but I cannot get it to work in JavaFX.

What I want is to load an external applet into a SwingNode. The applet has music that automatically plays and I can hear it but I cannot see anything.

I'm struggling to find any relevant documentation or help on this.

My Code:

**ClientNew.java**

```
package rsclient.coregui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import rsloader.Loader;

public class ClientNew extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final Loader loader = new Loader(Loader.Game.OSRS);
                loader.applet.setLayout(null);
                loader.applet.resize(800, 550);

                JPanel gamepanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                gamepanel.add(loader.applet, BorderLayout.CENTER);

                swingNode.setContent(gamepanel);

                gamepanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });

        Tab tab = new Tab();
        tab.setText("My Tab");
        tab.setClosable(false);
        tab.setContent(swingNode);

        TabP ane tabPane = new TabPane();
        tabPane.getStyleClass().add("tabbedPane");
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        stage.setScene(
            new Scene(
                tabPane,
                1000, 650
            )
        );

        stage.setTitle("My APplication");
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Loader.java** (not my code but it seems to work. Will of course refactor later)

```
package rsloader;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.applet.AppletContext;
import java.applet.AppletStub;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import rsreflection.Reflector;

/***
 *@author Xel
 *@version 1.0
 *@project RSLoader
 *@file Loader.java
 *@date 18.10.2013
 *@time 10.43.48
 */
public class Loader implements AppletStub{
    //insane declarations
    public enum Game{OSRS, RS3, CLASSIC};
    public static final HashMap<String, String> Parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public Game game;
    public URL GamePack;
    public Applet applet;
    public String gameUrl;
    public String MClass;
    public Reflector loader;

    public Loader(Game g)
    {
        game = g;
        if(game == Game.OSRS)
            gameUrl = "http://oldschool69.runescape.com/";
        else if(game == Game.RS3)
            gameUrl = "http://world1.runescape.com/";
        else
            gameUrl = "http://classic2.runescape.com/plugin.js?param=o0,a0,s0";

        try {
            GetParams(new URL(gameUrl));
                        loader  = new Reflector(new URL[]{GamePack});
            applet = (Applet)loader.loadClass(MClass).newInstance();
            applet.setStub(this);
            applet.init();
            applet.start();
        } catch (IOException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void GetParams(URL url) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        List<String> params = new ArrayList<String>();
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            if(line.contains("param name"))
                params.add(line);
            if(GamePack == null) //retarted block
                if(line.contains("archive"))
                    if(game != Game.CLASSIC)
                        GamePack = new URL(gameUrl + line.substring(line.indexOf("archive=") + 8, line.indexOf(" ');")));
                    else
                        GamePack = new URL("http://classic2.runescape.com/" + line.substring(line.indexOf("archive=") + 8, line.indexOf(" code")));
            if(MClass == null)
                if(line.contains("code="))

                        MClass = line.substring(line.indexOf("code=") + 5, line.indexOf(".class"));
        }
        reader.close();

        for(String s : params)
        {
            Parameters.put(GetParamName(s), GetParamValue(s));
        }
    }

    public String GetParamName(String param)
    {
        try{
            int StartIndex = param.indexOf("<param name=\"") + 13;
            int EndIndex = param.indexOf("\" value");
            return param.substring(StartIndex, EndIndex);
        }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e)//classic handles some differently so why not just catch it =P
        {
            int StartIndex = param.indexOf("<param name=") + 12;
            int EndIndex = param.indexOf(" value");
            return param.substring(StartIndex, EndIndex);
        }
    }

    public String GetParamValue(String param)
    {
        try{
            int StartIndex = param.indexOf("value=\"") + 7;
            int EndIndex = param.indexOf("\">');");
            return param.substring(StartIndex, EndIndex);
        }catch(StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e)//and again :D
        {
            int StartIndex = param.indexOf("value=") + 6;
            int EndIndex = param.indexOf(">');");
            return param.substring(StartIndex, EndIndex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void appletResize(int arg0, int arg1) {
    }

    @Override
    public AppletContext getAppletContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getCodeBase() {
        try
        {
            if(game == Game.OSRS)
                return new URL("http://oldschool1.runescape.com/");
            else if(game == Game.RS3)
                return new URL("http://world1.runescape.com/");
            else
                return new URL("http://classic2.runescape.com/");
        }catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public URL getDocumentBase() {
        try
        {
            if(game == Game.OSRS)
                return new URL("http://oldschool1.runescape.com/");
            else if(game == Game.RS3)
                return new URL("http://world1.runescape.com/");
            else
                return new URL("http://classic2.runescape.com/");
        }catch(MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String arg0) {
        return Parameters.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isActive() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, SwingNode will only show lightweight nodes. Applet is a heavyweight class.

Comment: Interesting, I did try thing like JLabel and JButton and they worked with no issue. How could I verify this?

Comment: How about you use *webview* instead? embed it on your frame.

Comment: @Bravo You know I'm not putting this into a website, right?

Comment: @James_D Do you have any other suggestion for a method of doing what I need?

Comment: See the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html): they explicitly state it should be used only be used with lightweight components. I haven't written applets for about 15 years (has anyone?), but IIRC your applet class simply supplies some lifecycle methods and adds a panel of some kind to the applet itself. So, if the content of the applet is a lightweight Swing component, just place that directly in the `SwingNode`. If it's not, you are likely out of luck.

Comment: @James_D The thing is that it is not my applet that I want to embed in my application.

Comment: @James_D Sorry to bring it up again but, how come I can hear the music and sounds from the applet? I figured that if it couldn't handle a complex swing components then it wouldn't do anything with it.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what's happening. A heavyweight component has a native peer that is responsible for the actual rendering. A lightweight component is rendered entirely in Java. So it seems reasonable to expect that if SwingNode can only contain lightweight components it lacks the mechanism for connecting to a native peer (i.e. The SwingNode already has a rendering mechanism which simply invokes the Java defined rendering of the lightweight component). I can also see that none of that would necessarily prevent other (none rendering) code in the applet from executing.

Comment: So basically the sounds etc don't depend on a native peer; the rendering does so that's the part that fails. Note btw that Applet is not part of Swing, it's an AWT component.

Comment: How can I achieve the best or both worlds? I want to be able to fully change the look of the GUI.

Comment: LMFAO, Looking to do the same exact thing as you, and was getting the same error, so I ended up here. Good luck with your adventures

Answer (score 1):

To ANYONE who is coming upon this question for rendering applets with JavaFX

Swing DOES NOT support the rendering of Heavyweight components.
There is still, and has not been any support for heavyweight components, which obviously sucks for people looking to render heavyweight games or applications with javafx.

Comment: JApplet is a lightweight component.
https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~mitra/csSpring2010/cs313/lectures/swing.html

Answer (score 0):

I also was trying to implement a swing applet into JavaFX.  I could not see the app.  After getting the size of the root pane I saw that it's Dimension was 0,0. The applet doesn't autosize with JavaFX.  I added the following line to my init method in the `JApplet`.

```
this.getRootPane().setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,600));
```

This allowed me to set the size of the applet. I am working on implementing a listener so that it will size with the window.

Comment: Awesome, let me know how this goes.